# Why do compilers use assembly language? what is the purpose of this?

Tags: assembly

I wonder what is the purpose of assembly language

To build a program computer changes high-level language to assembly language, and then changes assembly language to machine language.

```
HLL(high level language) -> AL(Assembly language) -> ML(machine language)
```

But why we use AL? Is it not possible to change HLL to ML directly?

Comment: Because assembly is human readable, machine code is not.

Comment: Yes it's possible to go from HLL to ML, some compilers emit machine code directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some compilers actually generate machine code directly. Some use their own intermediate language (see for example [LLVM Intermediate Represenation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LLVM#Intermediate_representation)), and some generate assembly code.

Some of the reasons for compiler to use assembly is:

- when it does not have a machine code generator for target platform, and relies on already available assembler for this platform.
- when it wants to show to a user (human readable) result of compilation

Comment: Having (human readable) assembly output could also be helpful to the compiler designers.